# How to fade out div when user is inactive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer, settimeout

this should be easy but I just can't get it to work as it should... I have a div element serving as a button. I do not want the button to be visible all the time, just to appear when the user touches the screen (with finger or mouse), stays visible for a period of time (say 2 seconds) after inactivity and then disappear.

I do not want it to disappear 2 seconds after it was made visible (for that I could just use jQuery delay), I want it to disappear 2 seconds after the user has stopped interacting with the screen (i.e. the #grid element in my case). As long as the user is touching the screen or moving the mouse the button is visible, when he stops that activity 2 seconds passes and the button goes away.

The following I have, it does not work:

```
var grid = $('#grid');
    grid.bind('mousemove touchmove tap swipeleft swipeup swipedown swiperight', function(e) { 
        var timer; 
        var circle= $('.circle-button');
        if (!circle.is(":visible")) {
            //button is not visible, fade in and tell it to fade out after 2s
            $('.circle-button').fadeIn('slow');
            timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('.circle-button').fadeOut('slow') }, 2000);
        }    
        else {
            //button is visible, need to increase timeout to 2s from now
            if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function(){ $('.circle-button').fadeOut('slow') }, 2000);
        }    
    });
```

Even if the above would work it seems very inefficent to me, to reinitiate a timer for each mousemove (not sure this is a real issue though). If someone could help me with a working, reasonably efficient solution, it would be much appreciated.
Cheers!

--- EDIT -----
Thanks for the replies, they are all good. I ended up using Rohan Veer's suggestion below since it seems the most elegant solution to me, not having to reinitiate a timer at each mouse move.

Comment: First of all, use `.on()` insted of `.bind()` - it's the preferred method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var idleTime = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
//Increment the idle time counter every minute.
var idleInterval = setInterval(timerIncrement, 60000); // 1 minute

//Zero the idle timer on mouse movement.
$(this).mousemove(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
$(this).keypress(function (e) {
    idleTime = 0;
});
});

function timerIncrement() {
idleTime = idleTime + 1;
if (idleTime > 2) { // 2 minutes
    // fade out div
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: "try this" with no explanation of what you've done or how it solves the OP's question is only marginally helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can set a timeout of desire time and on elapse, hide it. Following is a [Reference JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/wryu2xqx/).

#### Code

```js
var interval = null;

function initInterval(){
    if(interval)
        clear();
    
    showElement();
 interval = setTimeout(function(){
     $(".btn").fadeOut();
        clear();
    },2000);
}

function clear(){
 window.clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
}

function showElement(){
 $(".btn").fadeIn();
}

function registerEvents(){
    console.log("Events registering");
 $(document).on("mousemove", function(){
     initInterval();
    });
}

(function(){
 registerEvents();
})()
```

```css
.btn{
    width:200px;
    background:blue;
    color:#fff;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn">Will hide in 2 secs</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems pretty close to a working solution, I've made only a couple of slight changes. Pretty much the only way to do this is to set a timer on every move, but also clear the previous timer.

The code below works according to your description.

```js
var timer; 
var grid = $('#grid');
grid.bind('mousemove touchmove tap swipeleft swipeup swipedown swiperight', function(e) { 
    var circle= $('.circle-button');
    if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    if (!circle.is(":visible")) {
        circle.fadeIn('slow');
    }    
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ circle.fadeOut('slow') }, 2000);
});
```

```css
#grid{
    width:200px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="grid"></div>
<button class="circle-button">A button</button>
```